# Using JQuery/Masonry to organize a series of list items with page breaks at a given height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, layout, jquery-masonry

I am trying to create a way to fit as many formulas (part of a ul - though any other suggestions are welcome) into letter sized pages using Masonry i.e. have a page break, once the total height of all the formulas reaches [x].

I have an example here of what I'm trying to do (without the page break): http://notesnack.com/NoteSnack/cards/cheatsheets/cheatsheet:62

The above example does everything, except that as the number of formulas increases, the height of the page increases and I'm not able to put in page breaks (e.g. if i wanted to print the formulas, it would cut them off).

Below is a more abstract example:

Given: every layout-card contains a formula of x height with one of 4 different possible widths

```
<div class = "page-sized-container">
<ul id="masonry">
<li class="layout-card">
    <ul>
        <li>formula 1</li>
    </ul>
</li>
 .....
<li class="layout-card">
    <ul>
        <li>formula 15</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<!-- SOME SORT OF PAGE BREAK WHEN THE HEIGHT REACHES X HEIGHT -->
<li class="layout-card">
    <ul>
        <li>formula 16</li>
    </ul>
</li>
.....
<li class="layout-card">
    <ul>
        <li>formula 30</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do have a page break, once the combined height of the formulas (organized by jquery) reaches a pre-determined height.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you just not maintain page height you have to manage no of calls of masonary

Comment: hey thanks for your comment, could you clarify what you mean? are you saying that I can measure page height by somehow managing the calls to masonry?

Comment: yes masonary always pass a page not with it call
when it reaches 15 then stop